# PHP Form Validation on Server-side

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a php form and i need 4 field data to be submitted.

1. Name
2. Email
3. Password
4. Mobile

Now i have to check if all the above data is available or not.

For debugging purpose i am use $_GET below

```
if (!empty($_GET['name']) or !empty($_GET['email']) or !empty($_GET['password']) or !empty($_GET['mobile'])) {
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'OK',
        'error' => '1',
        'message' => 'Registered successfully. Please check your email for activation details',
        'data' => '');
} else {
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'NOK',
        'error' => '1',
        'message' => 'There was some error please try again.',
        'data' => '');
}
```

The above is not able to validate the form properly.

Comment: i am not able to get this to work

Comment: Use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead of empty. Also take a look at the [filter_var function](http://nl1.php.net/filter_var)

Comment: To ask a question you have to explain desired result. At least

Comment: why you use $_GET instead $_POST?

Comment: @PhilipsTel to test i am using GET i have mentioned in the question

Comment: don't forget to escape user's inputs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is important to use `and` in the condition, not `or`:

```
if (!empty($_GET['name']) and !empty($_GET['email']) and !empty($_GET['password']) and !empty($_GET['mobile'])) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Most forms are submitted using `method="POST"` which means on the PHP side you should be using `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

You also have a logic error, you want to proceed only if they are all filled in, therefore you want to use `and` instead of `or`.